# Show an External React App into Angular 6 using iframe

Tags: angular

I am looking to embed a react application into angular 6. Is there anyway I can achieve this using iframe or any way I can go about it?

I did `npm i MyReactApp` into my angular, 
then in one of my angular components, I tried to import it in,

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyReactComp from 'react/build/modules/component/index';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html'
})
protected render() {
      ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyReactComp , null), this.getRootDomNode());
  }
ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.render();
  }
```

It is giving me errors. It is unable to find the paths that are related/dependent to `MyReactComp` component. It only sees that file and won't look at the other imports into `MyReactComp`. How can I go about this?

Before you say, why would I want to do this? It is because we are trying to integrate into another department.

Comment: But wouldn't that React App be already deployed? And you'll have a URL to visit it?

Comment: Good question ^^
Sorry there is no answer after 4 years :(  I'm interested by the same solution - my angular application need to have react component loaded... But the setting is only possible throw the URL... A solution could be using an ifram... but I do not know how to do the implementation